# How can I fix this array issue? Car storage program

Tags: java

I am having trouble with arrays. Basically, I'm making a car storage problem for my CS course and instead of asking them to input the year, make, model separately I want them to be able to input, for example, "2019 Honda Civic Type R".

```
    final String[] properName = carName.split(" ");
    System.out.println(properName.length);

    // Tags mean like (SI, Type R, R, RS/SS, etc)
    String tags = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < properName.length; i++) {
        if (properName.length >= 4) {
            tags = properName[i];
        }
    }
```

As you can see, I'm splitting the string so I can create a new car object like: *new Car(properName[0] (year), properName[1] (make), properName[2] (model), etc).*

My problem is with cars that have names longer than 4 arguments. For example, "2019 Subaru WRX STI" has no problem, but "2019 Honda Civic Type R" returns "2019 Honda Civic R".

I'm sorry if this makes no sense. I'm terrible at explaining things.

Comment: Your code has returned "R" for me, what you count as a valid return?

Comment: If the input was "2019 Honda Civic Type R", I would want it to return "2019 Honda Civic Type R", not "2019 Honda Civic R".

Comment: You are making it very hard for yourself by allowing this kind of free text input. Ask separate questions for year, model etc instead.

Comment: your question is about parsing and not really about arrays. String.split method has a **limit** parameter to prevent splitting after a certain token. I would suggest to require a specific separator symbol like semicolon, comma , color instead of white-space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to collect the car tags'names in the tag variable. The car name of more than two words is a tag name.

```
public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String carName = "2019 Honda Civic Type R";

    final String[] properName = carName.split(" ");
    System.out.println(properName.length);

    // Tags mean like (SI, Type R, R, RS/SS, etc)
    StringBuilder tags = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 3; i < properName.length; i++) {
        tags.append(properName[i]).append(" ");
    }
   System.out.println(tags.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: for (i=3; i<len; i++) { tags. append(... I think no need another branch,and unnecessary spin

Answer (score 0):

The loop seems awfully redundant, first of all, you can just directly access the array like so `String tags = properName[properName.length - 1]`, but that wasn't your question.

In order to solve this problem, I would recommend just using regex

`^(\d+) (\w+) (\w+) ([\w ]+)` (match digits, then two words, then any more text consisting of word characters and spaces)

```
String car = "2019 Honda Civic Type R";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\d+) (\\w+) (\\w+) ([\\w ]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(car);
boolean matches = matcher.matches();
if (!matches) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid input!");

String year = matcher.group(1);
String make = matcher.group(2);
String model = matcher.group(3);
String type = matcher.group(4);
```